# how not to update/insert a sql table with null/blank value for a certain field

Tags: t-sql

How do I update a type 2 dimension table with some type 1 columns with the following requirement --If the newest entry from stage data is blank/NULL and previously a value existed-- do not update, only update if there is a different value and at the same time PREVENT the target table from inserting an additional row due to identifying a different/new value from stage (null/blank)  been that current data in dimension is not null).

```
            CREATE TABLE [dim].[patient](
            [dim_patient_current_de_key] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [id] [varchar](20) NULL,
            [client] [varchar](40) NULL,
            [DOB] [datetime] NULL,
            [Gender_Identity_code] [varchar](50) NULL,--type 2
            [dss_load_date] [datetime] NULL,
            [dss_start_date] [datetime] NULL,
            [dss_end_date] [datetime] NULL,
            [dss_current_flag] [char](1) NULL,
            [dss_version] [int] NULL,
            [dss_create_time] [datetime] NULL,
            [dss_update_time] [datetime] NULL,
            [StateID_number] [varchar](240) NULL,
            CONSTRAINT [dim_patient_demographi_idx_0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            -------- where the update (are for type 1 columns)
            UPDATE [dim].[dim_patient] WITH ( TABLOCK )
            SET     client =  changes.client_name
            , DOB =  changes.DOB
            , SSN =  changes.SSN
            , StateID_number = CASE 
                    WHEN NULLIF(changes.StateID_number, '') IS NULL THEN [TABLEOWNER].[dim_patient].StateID_number
                    ELSE changes.StateID_number
                    END
            , dss_update_time = @v_current_datetime
            FROM 
            (
            SELECT stage_patient.id  id
            , stage_patient.client  client
            , stage_patient.DOB  DOB
            , stage_patient.Gender_Identity_code
            , stage_patient.StateID_number  StateID_number
            FROM [stage].[stage_patient] stage_patient
            EXCEPT
            SELECT dim_patient.id  id
            , dim_patient.client  client
            , dim_patient.DOB  DOB
            , dim_patient.Gender_Identity_code
            , dim_patient.StateID_number  StateID_number
            FROM [dim].[dim_patient]
            WHERE dim_patient.dss_current_flag = 'Y'
            ) AS changes
            WHERE dim_patient.id = changes.id
            AND   dim_patient.dss_current_flag = 'Y'
            ----------------------------------------------------------------
            --============================================================================
            -- Insert new records
            --============================================================================
            INSERT INTO [dim].[patient] WITH ( TABLOCK )
            ( id
            , client
            , DOB
            , Gender_Identity_code
            , StateID_number
            , dss_load_date
            , dss_start_date
            , dss_end_date
            , dss_current_flag
            , dss_version
            , dss_create_time
            , dss_update_time
            )
            SELECT DISTINCT 
              stage_patient.id
            , stage_patient.client
            , stage_patient.DOB
            , stage_patient.Gender_Identity_code
            , stage_patient.StateID_number
            , stage_patient.dss_load_date
            , CASE WHEN vers.patid IS NULL
            THEN CAST('01-JAN-1900' AS datetime)
            ELSE @v_current_date
            END
            , CAST('31-DEC-2999' AS datetime)
            , 'Y'
            , CASE WHEN vers.patid IS NULL
            THEN 1
            ELSE vers.dss_version + 1
            END
            , @v_current_datetime
            , @v_current_datetime
            FROM [stage].[stage_patient] stage_patient
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT patid
            , MAX(dss_version) dss_version
            FROM [stage].[patient] patient
            GROUP BY id
            ) AS vers
            ON    stage_patient.id = vers.id
            EXCEPT
            SELECT patient.id  id
            , patient.client  client
            , patient.DOB  DOB
            , patient.StateID_number  StateID_number
            , source.dss_load_date  dss_load_date
            , @v_current_date
            , CAST('31-DEC-2999' AS datetime)
            , 'Y'
            , dss_version + 1
            , @v_current_datetime
            , @v_current_datetime
            FROM [dim].[patient] patient
            JOIN
            (
            SELECT stage_patient.id AS id
            , stage_patient.dss_load_date AS dss_load_date
            FROM [stage].[stage_patient] stage_patient
            ) AS source 
            ON    patient.id = source.id
            WHERE patient.dss_current_flag = 'Y'
```

Currently the code is inserting a second row with null for state_id which I dont want.

Comment: Sounds like a `where not exists`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

The `NULLIF()` function returns `NULL` when the first argument is `NULL` or when the first argument matches the second argument. So if the source value is blank or `NULL`, we update the column to itself. Otherwise, update to the new value.

```
UPDATE tgt
SET tgt.ColumnOne = CASE 
                      WHEN NULLIF(src.ColumnOne, '') IS NULL THEN tgt.ColumnOne
                      ELSE src.ColumnOne
                    END
FROM SourceTable AS src
JOIN TargetTable AS tgt
  ON src.KeyCol = tgt.KeyCol
WHERE EXISTS
(--Only update rows where the values of the column are different.
  SELECT src.ColumnOne
  EXCEPT
  SELECT tgt.ColumnOne
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I modified the question for a detailed explanation of what I am requesting but your answer brought some clarity.

Comment: How can I prevent it at the same time from inserting a new row to the target table despite spotting a difference between the incoming field with a null value and a target table with a non-value.

Comment: Use the same approach. Compare the fields for difference but if the source value field is null compare the target to itself